# Split text by paragraph

Tags: python, regex

I have such a sample text,

```
 ## Paragraph 1\n\nThe [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#module-sys) module also has attributes for *stdin*, *stdout*, and *stderr*. \n\nThe latter is useful for emitting warnings and error messages to make them visible even when *stdout* has been redirected:\n\n## Paragraph 2\n\nThe [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#module-re) module provides regular expression tools for advanced string processing. For complex matching and manipulation, regular expressions offer succinct, optimized solutions:\n\nWhen only simple capabilities are needed, string methods are preferred because they are easier to read and debug.
```

I'd like to split it to two paragraphs using regex instead of `str.split`, so I tried.

```
In [18]: para = re.findall(r'## .+', content)
In [19]: para
Out[19]: ['## Paragraph 1', '## Paragraph 2']
```

The output I intent is separated complete paragraph.

```
['## Paragraph 1\n\nThe [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#module-sys) module also has attributes for *stdin*, *stdout*, and *stderr*. \n\nThe latter is useful for emitting warnings and error messages to make them visible even when *stdout* has been redirected:\n\n',
'## Paragraph 2\n\nThe [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#module-re) module provides regular expression tools for advanced string processing. For complex matching and manipulation, regular expressions offer succinct, optimized solutions:\n\nWhen only simple capabilities are needed, string methods are preferred because they are easier to read and debug.']
```

How to accomplish it?

Comment: What language are you using? Usually there is a built-in string function for splitting strings, e.g. `split()` in JavaScript or `explode()` in PHP.

Comment: I add python as tag, thank you. @ssc-hrep3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = " ## Paragraph 1\n\nThe [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#module-sys) module also has attributes for *stdin*, *stdout*, and *stderr*. \n\nThe latter is useful for emitting warnings and error messages to make them visible even when *stdout* has been redirected:\n\n## Paragraph 2\n\nThe [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#module-re) module provides regular expression tools for advanced string processing. For complex matching and manipulation, regular expressions offer succinct, optimized solutions:\n\nWhen only simple capabilities are needed, string methods are preferred because they are easier to read and debug."
paragraphs = re.split('\n(?=## Paragraph \d+)', s)
```

Output:

```
 [' ## Paragraph 1\n\nThe [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#module-sys) module also has attributes for *stdin*, *stdout*, and *stderr*. \n\nThe latter is useful for emitting warnings and error messages to make them visible even when *stdout* has been redirected:\n', 
 '## Paragraph 2\n\nThe [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#module-re) module provides regular expression tools for advanced string processing. For complex matching and manipulation, regular expressions offer succinct, optimized solutions:\n\nWhen only simple capabilities are needed, string methods are preferred because they are easier to read and debug.']
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try the inbuilt split function**

```
string = '''I am new to python # please help me '''
data = string.split('#')
print(data)
```

**Output**

> > ['I am new to python ', ' please help me ']